# How to attach a disk in Kubernetes cluster in azure (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have deployed my running application in AKS. I want to add new disk (Harddisk of 30GB) but I don't know how to do it.

I want to attach 3 disks.

Here is details of AKS:

- Node size: `Standard_DS2_v2`
- Node pools: `1 node pool`
- Storage is:

---

```
default (default)   kubernetes.io/azure-disk   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   true
```

Please, tell me how to add it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#:%7E:text=A%20PersistentVolume%20(PV)%20is%20a,node%20is%20a%20cluster%20resource.&text=Pods%20can%20request%20specific%20levels%20of%20resources%20(CPU%20and%20Memory).):

> A *PersistentVolume* (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using [Storage Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).
>
> It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual Pod that uses the PV.

In the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage#persistent-volumes) one can find clear guides how to:

- [*create a static volume using Azure Disks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume)
- [*create a static volume using Azure Files*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume)
- [*create a dynamic volume using Azure Disks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv)
- [*create a dynamic volume using Azure Files*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv)

**NOTE**:
Before you begin you should have [existing AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough) and Azure CLI version 2.0.59 or [later installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and configured. To check your version run:

```
az --version
```

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

Comment: yes i have  existing aks cluster setup with running pods and azure cli 2.33.1 
im using default storage in aks (azure-disk) ...i try above links got fail because of outofmemory issue and some got pv,pvc both not bound dont know but i given correct storage in pv,pvc yaml file which show in above links

Comment: Please create new question with that problem (for clearness). Describe there your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

***A persistent volume represents a piece of storage that has been provisioned for use with Kubernetes pods. A persistent volume can be used by one or many pods, and can be dynamically or statically provisioned***.

This ***[article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv#before-you-begin)*** shows you how to dynamically ***create persistent volumes with Azure disks for use by a single pod*** in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster.

---

But if your requirement is to share the persistent volume across the multiple nodes use [***Azure FileShare***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv)

***This article shows you how to dynamically create an Azure Files share for use by multiple pods in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster.***

Comment: i tried with above links got issues